# Fixed Point Theorem in finite dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems

A [fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorem) says that:

"any continuous mapping of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a fixed point".

So consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $X$ is bounded. 
Is true that $f$ has a fixed point even if $X$ is not convex, as in the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem)?

I am wondering about the following example: $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1 \}$ and $f(x) = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right] x \in X$.

Is my example wrong and am I missing the meaning of the above Theorem?

Comment: Your counterexample does not map $\mathbb R^n\to X$.

Comment: If it was just $X\to X$, you'd be right...

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $X$ is bounded, $X$ is contained in some bounded convex closed ball $B$. Then, since $f_{\mid B}$ sends $B$ to $B$, it must have a fixed point.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am not sure I understand. The fact that $f$ has a fixed point in $B$ does not mean that such fixed point is in $X$, right?

Comment: @Adam If $f(x)\in X$ for all $x$, where should the fixed point be if not in $X$?

Comment: Since every image is in $X$, the only fixed points can be in $X$. You seem to think $f:X\to X$. It is $f:\mathbb R^n\to X$.

Comment: Yes, sure, now I see it. So if $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $X$, then I can define its restriction $f_{ | B} : B \rightarrow B$. This latter has a fixed point (because of Brouwer's Theorem) and takes values in $X$. Therefore the fixed point must be in $X$.

Comment: Yes, what your example shows is that you can't extend your function $X\to X$ without a fixed point to a function $\mathbb R^n\to X$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, correct. As you mention, I was thinking at $f:X \rightarrow X$, while the main point is that $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $X$.